# Google OAuth granular Consent

Tags: oauth

We manage a google application to manage google calendar for users of our real estate CRM.

Is there any sandbox way to test the new granular consent development before the deadline of 17th June?

Iw ould like to test my application before 17th to check the new Granular Consent before going on production

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/granular-permissions#test-your-updated-application-on-handling-granular-permissions - you could set the `enable_granular_consent parameter` to `true` in your sandbox environment.